# Using dplyr to select data from a specific hour and use that to compute a calculation

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a timeseries in Canada/mountain time. The data is per hour. Per day I want to take the F value at 0:29:05 (Fn) (Fn = F value just after midnight local time) and for each day I want to calculate Z=(Fn-F)/Fn

However, it needs to select Fn for  0:29:05 in Cadadian/Mountain and with each hour per-day z needs to be calculated using the Fn of that day.

Dummy data:

```
 datetime <- seq(
 from=as.POSIXct("2012-1-1 0:29:05", tz="Canada/Mountain"),
 to=as.POSIXct("2012-2-1 0:29:05", tz="Canada/Mountain"),
 by="hour")

 #variable F
 F <- runif(745, min = 0, max =2)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(datetime,F))
library(lubridate)
#make sure its in  "POSIXct" "POSIXt" format
df$datetime <- as_datetime(df$datetime)
```

Now I have already had some help in dplyr when using a minute data set - but obviously my understanding is still pretty poor as I cannot translate that to my hour-1 data example. Below is my attempt... and I am thinking perhaps mutate is the right option in this case?

```
df2 <- df %>%
group_by(Date = as.Date(datetime)) %>%
mutate(Fn = F[hour(datetime) == 0]), 
z = (Fn - F)/Fn) %>%
ungroup() %>%
select(-Date)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  library(lubridate)
  library(tidyverse)

datetime <- seq(
   from = as.POSIXct("2012-1-1 0:29:05", tz = "Canada/Mountain"),
   to = as.POSIXct("2012-2-1 0:29:05", tz = "Canada/Mountain"),
   by = "hour"
   )

f <- runif(745, min = 0, max =2) #variable f 
df <- data.frame(datetime, f)

# method using fill function from tidyr package
df2 <- df %>%
   mutate(Date = as.Date(datetime, tz = "Canada/Mountain")) %>% 
   left_join( #this will grab the f value at 0:29:05 of each day
     df %>% filter(hour(datetime) == 0) %>% select(datetime, Fn = f),
     by = 'datetime'
   ) %>% 
   group_by(Date) %>% 
   fill(Fn, Fn, .direction = 'down') %>% #fills in NA values with f values of the following day
   mutate(
     Z = ( Fn - f ) / Fn
   ) %>% 
   ungroup() %>% 
   select(-Date)

# method not using fill
df3 <- df %>%
   mutate(Date = as.Date(datetime, tz = "Canada/Mountain")) %>% 
   left_join( #this will grab the f value at 0:29:05 of each day
     df %>% filter(hour(datetime) == 0) %>% select(datetime, Fn = f),
     by = 'datetime'
   ) %>% 
   group_by(Date) %>% 
   mutate(
     Fn = na.omit(Fn),
     Z = ( Fn - f ) / Fn
   ) %>% 
   ungroup() %>% 
   select(-Date)

# both methods result in the same result, as shown below
# A tibble: 745 x 4
   datetime                f    Fn       Z
   <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 2012-01-01 00:29:05 0.590 0.590  0     
 2 2012-01-01 01:29:05 1.57  0.590 -1.66  
 3 2012-01-01 02:29:05 0.537 0.590  0.0900
 4 2012-01-01 03:29:05 0.691 0.590 -0.171 
 5 2012-01-01 04:29:05 0.719 0.590 -0.218 
 6 2012-01-01 05:29:05 0.811 0.590 -0.374 
 7 2012-01-01 06:29:05 0.248 0.590  0.581 
 8 2012-01-01 07:29:05 1.98  0.590 -2.35  
 9 2012-01-01 08:29:05 0.839 0.590 -0.422 
10 2012-01-01 09:29:05 0.733 0.590 -0.242 
# ... with 735 more rows
```

Just a thought but you should not name R objects `F` since it is typically reserved for `FALSE` values.

Comment: Hi Thanks for you input... I am currently struggling to load the tidyverse package for which i think the fill function comes from? I am getting the following error: 

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
 .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyverse', details:
  call: utils::packageVersion(x)
  error: package ‘tibble’ not found
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 3.5.2 

I have tried to restart R and re-install dplyr, tidyverse and lubridate to no avail. Any tips?

Comment: The function `fill` is actually found in the `tidyr` package, so you may just install that, or try completely closing out of RStudio/R and then run `devtools::install_github("hadley/tidyverse")`.

Comment: Also, I adjusted my answer to include a method not using the `fill` function.

Comment: Awesome - The first way worked with tidyr and fill - i will try the second method to and try to understand the process. Thank you for your help - also sorry for the bad choice of F.... that was just for my dummy data set and not actually used in my real data, but good point for examples too.